# Why changing model names on diagram create variables with 1 on them

Tags: c#, visual-studio, entity-framework, visual-studio-2017

After changing names from the model i got from entity framework the variables have 1 on it.

I change `price_sources` now is `PriceSources` because no variable had that name. Same with `user_types` to `UserTypes`

But change `municipality` to `Municipality` and now is `Municipalities1`

```
    public virtual DbSet<Municipality> Municipalities1 { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Presentation> Presentations1 { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<PriceSources> PriceSources { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Price> Prices1 { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Product> Products1 { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<State> States1 { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<UserType> UserTypes { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Weeks> Weeks1 { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Year> Years1 { get; set; }
```

[image: enter code here]

How can I change the name without creating variables with 1 on the names. Remember those are autgenerated files. I dont want make changes and then lost them because another model update.

Answer (score 0):

I could solve it changing the names to plural compiling and then back to singular. Dont know if there is an easy way so get it right from start.

```
public virtual DbSet<Municipalitys> Municipalitys { get; set; }
public virtual DbSet<Presentations> Presentations { get; set; }
public virtual DbSet<PriceSources> PriceSources { get; set; }
public virtual DbSet<Prices> Prices { get; set; }
public virtual DbSet<Products> Products { get; set; }
public virtual DbSet<States> States { get; set; }
public virtual DbSet<UserType> UserTypes { get; set; }
public virtual DbSet<Week> Weeks { get; set; }
public virtual DbSet<Year> Years1 { get; set; }
```

**Edit:** Dont need compile. Only need make the changes on the edmx Diagram and save. Then check the changes on the context.cs file

[image]
Do the changes on the diagram and then